# Bootstrap 4 masonry effect responsiveness

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

I am trying to use bootstrap 4 masonry effect on my website. However, the cards aren't responsive. It is a basic page with no special effects.

Note that the page works perfectly on resizing browser window but not on a mobile screen. 
I want the cards to stack up on each other on mobile screens as they appear on resizing the browser window.
Here's the basic HTML code.

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
    .card-columns {
        -webkit-column-count: 3;
        -moz-column-count: 3;
        column-count: 3;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .card-columns {
        -webkit-column-count: 1;
        -moz-column-count: 1;
        column-count: 1;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="card-columns">

        <div class="card">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f9/Phoenicopterus_ruber_in_S%C3%A3o_Paulo_Zoo.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-body">
                <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f9/Phoenicopterus_ruber_in_S%C3%A3o_Paulo_Zoo.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-body">
                <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f9/Phoenicopterus_ruber_in_S%C3%A3o_Paulo_Zoo.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-body">
                <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f9/Phoenicopterus_ruber_in_S%C3%A3o_Paulo_Zoo.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-body">
                <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f9/Phoenicopterus_ruber_in_S%C3%A3o_Paulo_Zoo.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-body">
                <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have used the media queries in CSS. Still, the page just appears zoomed out on small screens.

Here's how it looks on mobile screens.

[image]

Here's a link to the website if you want to view it on your mobile: 
https://cocky-hermann-3927c7.netlify.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this code to the `<head>` of you HTML page:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

I noticed it works on your CodePen (at least in Chrome emulation) but on your website it started to work when I added the viewport. You can [read more about that here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp) if you are interested. Hope that helps.

Comment: This is it! It worked. I can't give you a vote becuase of my reputation but thanks a lot man. This was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Himanshu glad to help out and greatful you were able to get it to work

Answer (score 0):

In addition to crazymatt's answer, The DVGA and WXGA mobile screen resolutions are 640px and 768px wide respectively.  In other words, 600px width does not cover high-end mobile screen widths.  799px is a better breakpoint for mobile devices.  Low-res tablets and laptops normally start at 800px; so, this means that you will get a 3 column layout on pretty much all non-phone devices, but a 1-column layout on pretty much all phones.